# What is the benefit of the mergeMap in this @ngrx example?

Tags: ngrx, ngrx-effects

The following example is taken from the [@ngrx example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ngrx/example-app/master/src/app/effects/collection.ts).

I understand this observable this way. The first `map` function gets the `payload` which is the book to be added, again processed by the `mergeMap` where it saves to the database.

**Original Code:**

```
  @Effect()
  addBookToCollection$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(collection.ActionTypes.ADD_BOOK)
    .map((action: collection.AddBookAction) => action.payload)
    .mergeMap(book =>
      this.db.insert('books', [ book ])
        .map(() => new collection.AddBookSuccessAction(book))
        .catch(() => of(new collection.AddBookFailAction(book)))
    );
```

Can the below code do the same thing as the above? Why there is a `mergeMap` required?

**Modified Code:**

```
@Effect()
  addBookToCollection$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$
    .ofType(collection.ActionTypes.ADD_BOOK)
    .map((action: collection.AddBookAction) => 
      this.db.insert('books', [ action.payload ])
        .map(() => new collection.AddBookSuccessAction(action.payload))
        .catch(() => of(new collection.AddBookFailAction(action.payload)))
    );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although @cartant added the first answer, the answer as well as comments are hard to understand. Here is how I can explain this code.

In the *original code*, `this.actions$` is the **originating observable**. The observable created by the first `map` is the **outer observable**. The **inner observable** is the observable created by `this.db.insert`. Thus there are 3 observables here.

The **effect** is `addBookToCollection$`.

The purpose of this code (*original code*) is to generate a `addBookToCollection$` observable of type `Observable<action>`. The first `map` will create a `Observable<Book>`. This type is not what the effect is, so simply can't end with the first `map`. This `Observable<Book>` need to be converted to `Observable<Action>`.

We can use `switchMap` or `mergeMap` to convert the `Observable<Book>` to `Observable<action>`. Both of these convert a high order observable to a first order like below:

`Observable<Observable<Book> ----> Observable<Action>`

The `switchMap` is beneficial for the async operations where the latest inner observable will be emitted and that can be subscribed by @ngrx. But `mergeMap` is used to let all the inner observables go through as concurrent. So it will allow all the books selected by the user to generate observables from `this.db.insert`. In essence, the `mergeMap` takes the **outer observable** from `map` and merges with the **inner observable** from `this.db.insert` to generate a new first order observable.

The `mergeMap` takes the `book` (`action.payload` from the previous `map`) and pass it to `this.db.insert`. `this.db.insert` will generate an action via `collection.AddBookSuccessAction(book)` of type `Observable<Action>`. The `map` of `this.db.insert` returns that to the `mergeMap` and the `mergeMap` returns a first order `Observable<Action>`.

What's wrong with the `Modified Code`? The modified code uses only `map` which returns a high order observable of type `Observable<Observable<AddBookSuccessAction>>>`. This is not of the correct type of effect `addBookToCollection$` which should be of type `Observable<Action>`.